# BASH history manipulation: search replace

Tags: bash, regex

There is a really handy parameter/variable expansion feature in BASH that I don't see for history. I've checked man pages for history and for BASH itself. Not there ...maybe I missed it.

Example:
I use ssh a lot and I can do this with variable expansion.

```
host=foo@bar.org
```

Suppose I wanted to extract just the host -- rather, remove the username.

```
hostonly=${host##*@}
```

If I

```
echo $hostonly
```

I get:

```
bar.org
```

My question:
*Is it possible to do this with commandline history?*

eg.,

Command 1:

```
ssh foo@bar.org
```

Command 2:

```
ssh gary@!!:##*@
```

This doesn't work, of course, but can someone confirm whether or not this type of pattern matching is available?

Thanks!

Bubnoff

Comment: In my examples, it is not particularly advantageous to do what I'm asking. Forget the character counts -- I'm basically just wondering about regex support in bash history substitution. Can it work similarly to variables, in other words. I know about quick s&r with carets as well as the !!:s/// form. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2):

A neat trick often missed by people is the `r` command (which is itself a special case of the `fc` command):

```
$ ssh foo@bar.org
(...)
$ r foo=baz
```

The more general case is

```
$ fc -s foo=bar ssh
```

which lets you select a command from the history by substring, then perform the specified substitution and run it.  If you leave off the `-s`, it will load the command into `$EDITOR` for more complex modification; command line editing mostly makes this unnecessary, but there are some edits that are hard to do on the command line.

You can also do fairly complex manipulation using `!` history reference syntax, but for historical reasons (the basic history mechanism was established by early `csh` and all enhancements have mostly kept compatibility) it uses a different syntax.  See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) for details.

Comment: `r` is an alias which probably needs to be defined (some installations may include it by default in `.bashrc`). `fc` still only does string substitutions (it doesn't support wildcards).

Comment: It will also depend on `bash` version; `r` was inherited from `ksh`, and `bash` 4 seems to be removing all the `ksh`-isms.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ ssh foo@bar.org
...
$ ^foo^gary^
...
```

The command is repeated using "gary" as the username instead of "foo". The following works the same way:

```
$ ssh foo@bar.org
...
$ !!:s/foo/gary/
...
```

Comment: I was aware of these methods. But depending on the strings, wildcards would be much quicker. How much regex support is there for examples like your second?

Comment: The last caret is unnecessary in example one

Comment: @Bubnoff: Unfortunately, Bash history substitution doesn't support wildcards. Zsh, however, does.

Comment: @Bubnoff: The last slash is also unnecessary in the second example.